# Firefox 48 and Selenium timeout issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

I am unable to run my tests on **Firefox 48** using latest Selenium versions (**2.53, Selenium 3 beta**).

Please explain the configuration needed and the code to use to successfully run tests on Firefox 48. I have pointed to the geckodriver and tried to initialise the same in my code.

**Code**:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Work\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.9.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = null;
driver = new MarionetteDriver();
```

**Getting the below**:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "PATH TO GECKO DRIVER");
DesiredCapabilities ffCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
ffCapabilities.setCapability("marionette",true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffCapabilities);
```

Comment: It worked. I missed to set the desired capabilities. Thanks a lot Ranjith's and @QA Square

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `DesiredCapabilities`. Add this line before driver initialization.

`DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`

Answer (score 0):

You can download geckodriver from the link
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
Then save the file in your local system. unzip the file and change the application name as "wires.exe". 
Then specify the path upto wires.exe in the code.

add selenium-2.53.0 jar files.

Try below code to start working on FF 47.0 or above.

```
package com.marionette.programs;
```

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver;

public class HandleLatestFirefox {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println(currentDir);
    //String marionetteDriverLocation = currentDir + "G:\\ravik\\Ravi-Training\\Selenium\\Marionette for firefox\\wires.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:\\ravik\\Ravi-Training\\Selenium\\Marionette for firefox\\wires.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdgc21jJHOAhVCvY8KHZ4aCdcQPAgD");
    System.out.println("marionette working fine....");

}
```

}